# Trying to send and receive message using protobuf in java,but got error: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

The problem happened at server end, parseDelimitedFrom() calling.

Client End:

```
    C2SGainCard.Builder s = C2SGainCard.newBuilder();
    C2SGainCard c2s = s.build();

    GameRequest.Builder  reqBuilder=GameRequest.newBuilder();
    reqBuilder.setBody(c2s.toByteString());
    reqBuilder.setName(C2SGainCard.class.getSimpleName());
    reqBuilder.setPlayerId("3");
    GameRequest request=reqBuilder.build();

    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    os.write(request.toByteArray());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    socket.close();
```

Server End:

```
    try{
        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        GameRequest gameRequest = GameRequest.parseDelimitedFrom(is);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

And here is the another similar question:

Client End:

```
    C2SSell.Builder s = C2SSell.newBuilder();
    CardOnSell.Builder cardOnSell = CardOnSell.newBuilder();
    cardOnSell.setId(1);
    cardOnSell.setPlayerId(3);
    cardOnSell.setCardId(1);
    cardOnSell.setCurrentPrice(111);
    cardOnSell.setFixedPrice(555);
    cardOnSell.setDescription("cao");

    s.setCardOnSell(cardOnSell.build());

    C2SSell c2s = s.build();
```

socket processing was the same.

Server End:

```
    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int len=is.read(b);
    String as = new String(b, 0, len);
    GameRequest gameRequest=GameRequest.parseFrom(as.getBytes());
```

Turns out that the server end will break at the parseFrom() calling again.But when I comment two lines:

```
cardOnSell.setCurrentPrice(111);
cardOnSell.setFixedPrice(555);
```

on the client End,the parseFrom() calling just worked without problem. At frist I suspected the .proto file has some problems and it's been proved there is no problem there... So how does this problem come? It that because I miss some data before the parseFrom() calling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't remember exactly what format `parseDelimitedFrom` expects, but I *suspect* you just want `parseFrom` in your server side.

It's not clear why you're using `os.write(request.toByteArray())` though, or indeed why you're creating a `DataOutputStream`. You should be able to use just `OutputStream` and `InputStream`, writing:

```
request.writeTo(socket.getOutputStream());
```

and then:

```
GameRequest gameRequest = GameRequest.parseFrom(socket.getInputStream());
```

If you *do* want the delimited version, you need to use `writeDelimitedTo` instead.

Comment: thanks,dude,your solution really does work..but I still have no idea why I got such a problem.At first,my server code was like this:`DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());`  `byte[] b = new byte[1024];`   `is.read(b);`   `GameRequest.parseFrom(b);`  and When I change the code like above, it just broke down...

Comment: @RyanZhu: *Never* call `InputStream.read(byte[])` and ignore the return value. That may well have only read part of the data. Even if it didn't read just part of the data, you'd end up with a byte array which is then *longer* than expected, with trailing zeroes which would mess things up. Basically, there's a very good reason that Protocol Buffers supplies a method to read it from a stream - you might as well use that!

Comment: The Java version of Protocol Buffers supports writing multiple Protocol Buffers to the same file (with a Length Delimiter before each Protocol Buffer). parseDelimitedFrom is for reading these Length-Delimited files.

Comment: @BruceMartin: Yes, I'm aware of that - but as the OP didn't use `writeDelimitedTo`, using `parseDelimitedFrom` is going to fail.